# $A\in M_{n}(F)$ is similar to an upper triangular matrix if and only if its minimal polynomial is a product of linear polynomials in $F$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Here's my argument:

Let $A$ be similar to an upper triangular matrix $U$. Note that similar matrices have same minimal polynomial. Observe that $xI-U$ is also upper triangular matrix. Hence  the characteristic polynomial $m_{U}(x)=\det(xI-U)$ of $U$ is a product of linear polynomials in $F$ since the determinant of an upper triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal entries. Since minimal polynomial of $U$ divides its characteristic polynomial, then the minimal polynomial is also a product of linear polynomial, as desired.

Is this correct?

Comment: actually, if the minimal polynomial is squarefree, the matrix is diagonalizable. Next, every matrix is similar to its Jordan form, which is upper triangular. Your apparent question is misleading in a couple of ways

Comment: @WillJagy I suspect $F$ is supposed to be a general field, which is not necessarily complete, so the Jordan form over $F$ may not exist.